# Disable spell checking in Word 2016 for one single document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, spell-check, microsoft-word-2016

How can I disable the spell checking in Word 2016 for one single document only and not for all the others I'll open afterwards?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hide spelling errors in the current document like so:

File > Options (bottom left) > (2) Proofing > (3) *Hide spelling errors in this document only*

[image]

Comment: I would like to do the same with PowerPoint, but there is no "Exceptions for:" section there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

All Word paragraph styles inherit from the *Normal* style. If you edit the *Normal* style not to check grammar and spelling mistakes, it will affect every style in the whole document.

To do so, go to the edit menu of the Normal paragraph style, then format > language and check the "don't check" box.

If you only wish to turn off the spell checking for the current document, not all new documents be sure to select *Only in this document*.

[image]